# Can only see my app in the play store on mobile phone not tablet

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I am able to see my published app in the Google Play store on my Jellybean 4.1.2 phone and my Google Nexus 7 on KitKat but when using a Samsung tab 3 on Jellybean 4.1.2 I cannot see the app in the store

Comment: Kindly check your google play store account settings for you android app.

Comment: do you have define camera or telephony permission in your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Why downvote for this question? For downvoter: You should add a comment also behind the downvote so that user can update his question. It is a very common problem in android.

Comment: I do define camera but the Samsung tab has a camera, I do not define telephony. Which settings should I check on my Google Play Store account. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it saying, app is not compatible.

It is showing error on device not only because minSDKversion but also google play concern about your given permission on the manifest file as well.

Like if you entered something like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Your tab will not support it.

So instead of using `uses-permission` use  `<uses-feature>`. And in java file check for it that your needed hardware is available or not.

For `<uses-feature>` see the below link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#features-reference

**In case If you use this you have to update your manifest like this:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false"/>
```

You have to put `<uses-permission>` along with its required `<uses-feature>`.

Comment: It is not saying app is not compatable but is not appearing at all in the app store, but is fine when run through Eclipse. I will check these settings tomorrow. Thank you for your help.